# Server fails to boot with lvm error : ¨Invalid argument for --available: ay Error during parsing of command line.¨

Tags: centos, lvm

We have problems with our storage server, it was not updated for a while so we tried to updated it, tho during the update process (it needed some 2k package updates) it totally blacked out. (no screen on the motherboard, ssh dead, but still some io on the disks: blinking leds)

We rebooted the machines to see whats going on. The boot failed and we got this error :

```
Server fails to boot with lvm error : ¨Invalid argument for --available: ay Error during parsing of command line.¨
```

The only solution I could find is on redhat knowledge bank and is protected by a paywall :(

I have verified that all the data on the root (ext4) and home (ext4) are both oke and can be accessed using a rescue disk.  I could also mount these and gain access. So I'm pretty sure this is a configuration error. I have however no idea how to fix it.

This is running on a centos 6 machine, its saying (etc/redhat-release) that its 6.7 but I think its older, and that 6.7 is the upgraded version.

I'm not sure if its usefull in this context but I dumped (grep -v '#') the config [/etc/lvm/lvm.conf](http://dumptext.com/3arJpFTL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
initscripts versions greater or equal to 9.03.32-1 and below 9.03.38-1
lvm versions below lvm2-2.02.97-2.el6
```

Only happens during a crash of yum transaction. Upgrading both packages to latest should solve the issue.